# set "checkPointLocation" is not reflecting when run the spark job in "cluster" mode " how to fix this?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with kafka 0.10.x using java 1.8.
Even though  checkPointLocation is set ,  spark job is not reflecting/honoring when I run in "cluster" mode.

trying to write in **"/tmp/hadoop-admin/nm-local-dir/usercache"** location

how to fix this ?

**Code :**

```
StreamingQuery queryComapanyRecords = 
            comapanyRecords
              .writeStream()
              .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir )
              .parquet(parquetDir)
             .start()
```

[image]

> Why spark-submit script is something as below

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name CompanyConsumer  \
```

It is trying to create local directory as below

```
[main] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager - Created local directory at /tmp/hadoop-admin/nm-local-dir/usercache/analytics/appcache/application_1573726329182_0973/blockmgr-bab216a4-18e2-4fe3-a8f7-0177a1809dee
```

> Can this be set to hdfs folder ?

Comment: Could you please add in your code?

Comment: Thanks, is this ("checkpointLocation") a HDFS location?

Comment: Not clear what the error is. The checkpoint shouldn't be stored in local dirs, but in HDFS anyway, so what variable did you pass?

Comment: I don't really know how the user account is changing to admin if you've submitted the job as the analytics user. But you can fix the problem by running `chmod -R 777 /tmp` over all the nodemanagers